# Ocultar valores que no tienen nada escrito

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy usando **google apps scripts** para enviar un correo de acuerdo a ciertos valores que se llenan en un macro, el problema viene cuando quiero enviar una fecha.

```
var fecha = new Date(registro.getRange("c16").getValue());
var fechaF = Utilities.formatDate(fecha, "GMT","DD-MM-YYYY");
```

Este es el código que tengo por el momento, así lo repito con 6 fechas más. Me envía la fecha y la transforma en este formato. Mi macro puede llenarse completamente o solo una parte.

Cuando solo se llena el principio y no hay datos en los demás valores donde irían las fechas me envía una fecha aleatoria, o no sé bajo que criterio determine esa fecha, el punto es que no hay nada escrito y busco que ***si no tiene nada escrito en esa parte no se envié nada***. **¿Cómo podría conseguir esto?**

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que es porque cuando haces el new Date de un campo nulo te da el valor de la primera fecha válida de new Date que es el 1 de enero de 1970. Puedes probar:

```
var fechaCelda = registro.getRange("c16").getValue();
var fecha = !fechaCelda || fechaCelda === "" ? null : new Date(fechaCelda);
var fechaF = !fecha ? "" : Utilities.formatDate(fecha, "GMT","DD-MM-YYYY");
```

No se si te valdrá, ya que no puedo saber bien lo que devuelve `registro.getRange("c16").getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de

```
var fecha = new Date(registro.getRange("c16").getValue());
var fechaF = Utilities.formatDate(fecha, "GMT","DD-MM-YYYY");
```

usa

```
var fecha = new Date(registro.getRange("c16").getValue());
if(fecha instanceof Date){
   var fechaF = Utilities.formatDate(fecha, "GMT","DD-MM-YYYY");
   // agrega aquí el resto
} else {
  // pon aquí lo que se debe hacer en caso de C16 no tenga una fecha
}
```